# Is it possible to get original after json_encode?

Tags: php, laravel

First step:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

$str = json_encode($arr);
```

Is it possible to get the original array from `$str` if I don't have easy access to `$arr`?

Comment: json_decode, then continue handle the variable

Comment: Would you believe `json_decode($str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can decode using `json_decode`.
Use this to get original array.

```
$arr = json_decode($str,true)
```

for more detail [click here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = json_decode($str);
```

Google is your friend, failing that php.net

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your arrays to JSON with

```
$encode = json_encode($array);
```

But you can also decode it. This way you get the original array back:

```
$decode = json_decode($encode);
```

Hope this helps you out :)